# Nginx properly setup fro Drupal9 site

Tags: nginx, caching, browser-cache, drupal-9

NGINX installed and it seems to miss everything. Now, I have two cache-control as on the image:
[Header cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pytam.png)

First cache-control is NGINX, and second is from my .htaccess file.

Can anyone help me to properly configure NGINX for Drupal9 site?